# access elements created by JavaScript at runtime (document.write)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, html-parsing

i am making an iphone app that get data from web ,i use HPPLE to parse the html ,all works fine but in same cases i have problem to access elements created dynamically by JavaScript (document.write) in html web page .this is my html web source [page source](http://kooora.com/?c=6423)

```
<table dir = "rtl .......">
<tbody>
<script src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=ajax&rev=3"......>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "get.aspx?type=js&file=mc&rev=6"></script>
<script>..</script>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<script>..</script>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

i can see all elements labelled < tr> with safari Browser's Developer Tools ,but when i try to download the html code the source that I get contains no html tags i want. sory of my bad english.and i hope some one help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to get JavaScript support is use a `UIWebView`. It doesn't need to be added to the view hierarchy.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
webView.delegate = self;
frames = 0; // NSUInteger instance variable to track frame loads
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

`UIWebViewDelegate` Methods

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    frames++;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    frames--;
    if (frames > 0) return;

    NSString *document = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

    // Use HPPLE to parse
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Handle error
}
```

Now that you have the `document` text, you could pass that to HPPLE

Comment: thanks Jason,what about webViewDidFinishLoad: this method called multiple .

Comment: That method is called once per frame on the page. If you know the page won't have framesets/iframes then you could assume it will be called only once

Answer (score 1):

You can get such HTML with Browser's Developer Tools. Right click on `<html>` tag there and chose "Edit as Html". Copy the this code and paste it to some html file.

You can also copy a partial code. In this case you need to right click on the specific tag, that contain code that you need (wrapping tag).

Comment: thans but i want to download the html data rather than copy and past

Comment: Than you're in trouble, my friend. Tools like "wget" won't be able to help you. You'd need to download the javascript and reproduce its actions.

Comment: its more than html parsing. Its parsing and executing javascript. I've never done something like that. If I'd need to do it - I would start with googling on topic: "browser framework"

Answer (score 1):

I've never used hpple myself, but looking at the description, it says nothing about parsing and executing javascript.

What you are seeing in Safari Browser Tools is a visual representation of the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). This is what the browser generates from the HTML. Javascript can be used to modify it after the initial HTML is loaded.

hpple is designed to parse the original HTML, but will not include any DOM elements that would be created using javascript. So your stuck there. Hopefully somebody here knows of a tool that can parse javascript so that you can do what you want.